# Two people using the same computer at the same time remotely!

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, terminal-services, multiple-users

We have two computer in office and two people. My computer is much more faster than another computer. Is it possible my colleague connect to my computer remotely and work by my computer?

Using "Remote Desktop" in Windows only one user can log into computer. So when he connect remotely, my user logged off. Is there a tool which can help in this case?

I already knew VNC (RealVNC) But it's not helping because when a user connect to my computer, he see exactly my desktop, not his own user desktop.

Comment: I already seen this question http://superuser.com/questions/212061/two-users-using-the-same-computer-with-windows-7-at-the-same-time-one-locally-o But the answers did not help me. I want TWO USERS work with the same computer in TWO DIFFERENT environment. AFAK Real VNC remote sessions all can see a same desktop which is not what I wanted

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: My computer (the powerful one) is Windows 7 and the computer which want I want to connect to this computer is using Windows XP!

Comment: I've seen one system serving multiple sessions on linux using VNC and I've seen the same thing using remote desktop using the server edition of windows (terminal services server). I have not seen a solution for non-server editions of windows to serve more than one session.

Comment: Currently, consumer versions of Windows does not allow this.  Only Windows Server allows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution. [MissingRemote](http://www.missingremote.com/) published a patch which solve the problem in Windows 7 and allow concurrent remote session.

Here they are:
[Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://www.missingremote.com/guide/how-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-service-pack-1-beta)
[Windows 7 No Service Pack](http://www.missingremote.com/guide/how-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7)

You might have to edit install.cmd manual and remove :VERSIONCHECK because this script is very tightly check your Windows Build version. My windows build version 7600 and it wall not prompting that this OS is not supported. I removed :VERSIONCHECK section and it installed fine.

The solution is brilliant and is working pretty well for me.